# vba outlook attachment data in excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, attachment

I searched through the web but didn't find any specific code to help me.
I want to implement a VBA function in Outlook that execute, every time an email containing an attachment come, the following things, in order:

1) it reads the date of the email it was Sent, and depending on the month and the week inside the month (first, second, third...) stores the file in a folder. If the folder does not exist, it creates it (for example, a file sent on 22/10/2014 would be stored in the folder .../2014/October/4)

2) it uploads an Excel file with: sender name, date of the email, number of the week it is stored, name of the attachment, extension. In the end, it saves the Excel list and close it.

I found some part of code that do single actions, but whenever I try to put them together, it becomes a mess and doesn't work.

Comment: What code have you already tried?  What errors are you getting?  SO is not a request for code site.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Application.NewMail or NewMailEx events to get notified when new emails are delivered.  Then evaluate MailItem.SentOn (Date) or MailItem.Attachments.Count to run your business logic.  Use Attachment.SaveAsFile to write the attachment to disk.